# WCF add attribute to soap body

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf

i need to add an attribute to body element. How can i do this?

```
<soapenv:Body wsu:Id="body">
```

I'm using XmlSerializerFormat. My Code:

```
f[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://TSUtoMFC")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IService
{
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    [OperationContract]
    ResponseType SampleTestSmev();

}

    [MessageContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public class ResponseType
    {
        [MessageHeader]
        public SecurityType Security = new SecurityType();
        [MessageHeader]
        public smevheader header = new smevheader();
        [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315")]
        public MessageType Message = new MessageType();
        [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315")]
        public MessageDataType MessageData = new MessageDataType();
```

}

Comment: Have you tried anything?  You'll get more help if you share what you've tried.

Comment: Add [`[XmlAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the `Id` property of your body class.  Beyond that, please try to show what you have done so far.

Comment: @dbc  I do not have access to the body element, becuase it is soap envelope element

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IDispatchMessageInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector(v=vs.90).aspx) that enables custom modification of inbound and outbound messages.